# jQuery ajax error do nothing

Tags: jquery, error-handling

This is a very basic question, and shouldn't be as hard as it's turned out to be.

I have a CMS that I've developed. I am using ajax to change form parameters. When a user selects an option that has no "special params" i want nothing to display. Right now, I have ajax searching for a file. If the file exists, it should display it in the div. if it doesn't exist, I want nothing to be displayed. As of now, when the file doesn't exists the div is loaded with the entire page with a 404 error. I don't want to display errors, I just want nothing when the file doesn't exist.

This is what I have:

```
$.ajax({

url: '../components/com_'+PARAMS+'/menu.php',
success: function(result){
     $('#menuparams').html(result);
},
error: function(){
    $('#menuparams').html('');
}
});
```

Comment: Does you cms set a 404 http status code or just displays a page with a 404 message.

Comment: Just displays a page with 404 message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your path is routed to the CMS which is failing to send an HTTP response header. Either you forgot to send a 404 in the response header in your CMS or you sent text to the page before you tried to send the header.

If this is the case, you could either fix your CMS. Or you could check the success results for a 404 error.

#### Update

In your CMS when something is not found, before anything else gets sent you have to do:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
?>
```

There needs to be no characters at all including spaces sent to the web server before the call to header is made. I can't help you further than that without knowing more about the internals of your CMS.

Since you say you get nothing at all, I got to ask. What do you get when you open the URLs in a browser? Also could you post what URL you would use to open it in a browser and the contents of PARAMS.

Tell us what 
    console.log('../components/com_'+PARAMS+'/menu.php');
does. if you put it before
    $.ajax({

Comment: How do I check the success results? Everything I've tried so far doesn't send anything back.

Comment: The portion of the CMS that I am working on is navigation menu editing. The users are provided with a number of options for menutypes (Content,contact,photo gallery, etc.). When they chose the menu type, the params need to dynamically load for the menu type.

so the "PARAMS" is based on what menu type they select.

I have .htacces controlling 404 errors right now. I will try to remove that and see if that helps.

Comment: It was the .htaccess. It works now, however now I don't have customized 404 pages.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery code looks correct to me, the problem seems to be what your CMS is returning. Since you say the div is loaded with the entire page of a 404 error, it seems the CMS does not actually set a 404 status in the response, it just returns a 404 error page. In that case jQuery won't know it's an error and will execute the success function.

If you can get the CMS to set a 404 status, your jQuery code will work as expected. If you cannot, you could change your code to something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '../components/com_'+PARAMS+'/menu.php',
  success: function(data) {
     if ($(data).find(... something only the 404 error page has ...).length) {
       $('#menuparams').html('');
     } else {
       $('#menuparams').html(data);
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: How would I go about changing my CMS to set a 404 status in the response?

Comment: So here's the full problem. I have a htaccess file that routes all the pages through the CMS index page. From there the pages are handled using PHP and MySQL. The problem with using jQuery ajax is that it doesn't read 404 pages while the .htaccess file is active. Is there anyway I can get information about the file ajax gets? That way if I can set a variable to be flagged, I know it's the 404 page instead of a CMS page?